# R - negate values at specified positions in a integer vector

Tags: r, vectorization

I want to apply logical `NOT` to the specified indexes of a binary integer vector.

**Example:** given `c(0, 1, 0)` and `c(1, 3)`, I want to obtain `c(1, 1, 1)`.

What's a vectorized way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = c(0, 1, 0) 
Changes = c(1, 3)
x[Changes] = !x[Changes]
x
```

> ```
> [1] 1 1 1
> ```